# Encoding of Twilio call recordings

Tags: twilio, audio-recording

I'm creating a tool using Twilio where I record upon request bits of the call. I'm using [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/download/) to check the encoding of the file and if it is a Linear PCM, but in part of [Twilio's documentation](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180588-Best-Practices-for-Audio-Recordings) it is stated that a call is using an 8-bit PCM mono uLaw with a sampling rate of 8Khz.

Can this be configured, because I'd need to have the recording in a given encoding configured by me when launching the recording or when downloading it.
Upon fetching the recording I can only choose mp3 or wav.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recording format is not a configurable option.

Note that calls traveling across the Public Switch Telephone Network (PSTN) have their audio quality constrained by that transport. See the below article for more details.

You could download the recordings from Twilio and transcode to your required format, and store in your cloud.

[Best Practices for Audio Recordings](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180588-Best-Practices-for-Audio-Recordings)